# On bounding complex logarithm times complex power function

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

In my textbook (Ordinary Differential Equations by Andersson and Böiers), it is claimed that the complex modulus of $(\log(z))^jz^\lambda$, where $j\geq0$ is a natural number and $\lambda$ a complex number, can be bounded above by $c|z|^l$ for some integer $l$ and constant $c$. Assume we are on the branch $0\leq \mathrm{arg}(z)<2\pi$ and moreover, that this bound should hold near the origin. I have a hard time confirming this. Here's what I've tried so far.

Let $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ be the real and imaginary part of $\lambda$ respectively. By definition, $\log(z)=\ln(|z|)+i\mathrm{arg}(z)$. Then $$|(\log(z))^j|=|\log(z)|^j\leq\left(\sqrt{\ln(|z|)^2+4\pi^2}\right)^j,$$ and $$|z^\lambda|=|e^{\lambda\log(z)}|=e^{\lambda_1\ln(|z|)}e^{-\lambda_2\arg(z)}=|z|^\lambda_1e^{-\lambda_2\arg(z)}.$$

Then someone has pointed to the limit $\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{(\ln x)^r}{x^k}=0$ for $r,k>0$, yet I don't see how we can write my simplification as this limit, if I have understood things right. Maybe there's another approach. Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda=x+iy$. When $|z|>0$ is small,
$$
\begin{aligned}
|(\log z)^j|
&=|\log|z|+i\arg z|^j\\
&\le\big(\big|\log|z|\big|+2\pi\big)^j\\
&\le\left(\frac{1}{|z|}+2\pi\right)^j\\
&\le\left(\frac{2}{|z|}\right)^j,\\
|z^\lambda|
&=|\exp(\lambda\log z)|\\
&=\exp\big(\operatorname{Re}(\lambda\log z)\big)\\
&=\exp\big(x\log|z|-y\arg z\big)\\
&=|z|^xe^{-y\arg z}\\
&\le|z|^{\lfloor x\rfloor}e^{-y\arg z}\\
&\le|z|^{\lfloor x\rfloor}e^{\max\{0,-2\pi y\}}.\\
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore $|(\log z)^jz^\lambda|\le 2^je^{\max\{0,-2\pi y\}}|z|^{\lfloor x\rfloor-j}$.

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Could you explain the three first inequalities a bit more? In the last one, I assume you replace $2\pi$ with $1/|z|$, is that correct?

Comment: @sunny The first one follows from the triangle inequality and the assumption that $0\le\arg z<2\pi$. The second inequality follows from the inequality that $ye^{-y}<1$ when $y=-\log|z|>0$ is sufficiently large. The third one is $2\pi<\frac{1}{|z|}$ when $|z|$ is sufficiently small.